# Gson generic deserialize JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to build a websocket client using Gson.
As expected a websocket communication is based on several different messages.

I would like to have an elegant way to convert an JSON string to an declared model/object.

First attempt:

```
if message.contains("fieldA") {
    return gson.fromJson(message, ObjectA.class);
} else if message.contains("fieldB") {
    return gson.fromJson(message, ObjectB.class);
} else if message.contains("fieldC") {
    return gson.fromJson(message, ObjectC.class);
}
// etc
```

Second attempt, I've seen solutions with Generic and Arbitrary Types but is very similar to the first attempt. Instead of looking of the differentiating the Class I need to declare the Type. Which in written code is pretty similar.

What I think would be easier to have and maintain, would be to declare the models for the messages in some package and have one of these implementations.

1. Use a base Class/interface as a common ground for the `fromJson`
2. Register supported models somewhere so I could execute the parser simple as `gson.fromJson(messageString)`

There is a way like this or other to achieve a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a generic solution would be efficient due to linear complexity search required for the "contains" operation (unlike `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` that uses a discriminator type field), but it might be implemented like this:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class JsonElementTypeAdapterFactoryBuilder<V, J extends JsonElement> {

    private final Class<V> baseType;

    private final Collection<Rule<V, J>> rules = new ArrayList<>();

    public static <V, J extends JsonElement> JsonElementTypeAdapterFactoryBuilder<V, J> construct(final Class<V> baseType) {
        return new JsonElementTypeAdapterFactoryBuilder<>(baseType);
    }

    public JsonElementTypeAdapterFactoryBuilder<V, J> register(final Predicate<? super J> isSupported,
            final Supplier<? extends TypeToken<? extends V>> getTypeToken) {
        rules.add(new Rule<V, J>(isSupported, getTypeToken));
        return this;
    }

    public TypeAdapterFactory build() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Rule<V, J>[] rules = this.rules.stream()
                .toArray(Rule[]::new);
        return new TypeAdapterFactory() {
            @Override
            @Nullable
            public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
                if ( !baseType.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
                    return null;
                }
                final TypeAdapterFactory typeAdapterFactory = this;
                return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
                    private final Map<TypeToken<? extends V>, TypeAdapter<? extends V>> index = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

                    @Override
                    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public T read(final JsonReader in) {
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        final J jsonElement = (J) Streams.parse(in);
                        for ( final Rule<V, J> rule : rules ) {
                            if ( rule.isSupported.test(jsonElement) ) {
                                final TypeToken<? extends V> concreteTypeToken = rule.getTypeToken.get();
                                final TypeAdapter<? extends V> typeAdapter = index.computeIfAbsent(concreteTypeToken, tt -> gson.getDelegateAdapter(typeAdapterFactory, tt));
                                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                                final T value = (T) typeAdapter.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
                                return value;
                            }
                        }
                        throw new AssertionError(typeToken);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private static final class Rule<V, J extends JsonElement> {

        private final Predicate<? super J> isSupported;
        private final Supplier<? extends TypeToken<? extends V>> getTypeToken;

    }

}
```

with the following example:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .disableHtmlEscaping()
        .disableInnerClassSerialization()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(JsonElementTypeAdapterFactoryBuilder.<ICommon, JsonObject>construct(ICommon.class)
                .register(jsonObject -> jsonObject.has("fieldA"), () -> objectATypeToken)
                .register(jsonObject -> jsonObject.has("fieldB"), () -> objectBTypeToken)
                .register(jsonObject -> jsonObject.has("fieldC"), () -> objectCTypeToken)
                .build()
        )
        .create();
```

I'm not sure whether this implementation is super-optimized (all right, I give up, it is not), but I guess that the following implementation would be both simpler and more efficient (regardless no API):

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .disableHtmlEscaping()
        .disableInnerClassSerialization()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new TypeAdapterFactory() {
            @Override
            @Nullable
            public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
                if ( !ICommon.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
                    return null;
                }
                final TypeAdapter<ObjectA> aTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, new TypeToken<ObjectA>() {});
                final TypeAdapter<ObjectB> bTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, new TypeToken<ObjectB>() {});
                final TypeAdapter<ObjectC> cTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, new TypeToken<ObjectC>() {});
                return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public T read(final JsonReader in)
                            throws IOException {
                        final JsonElement jsonElement = Streams.parse(in);
                        final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement
                                .getAsJsonObject();
                        final TypeAdapter<? extends ICommon> typeAdapter;
                        if ( jsonObject.has("fieldA") ) {
                            typeAdapter = aTypeAdapter;
                        } else if ( jsonObject.has("fieldB") ) {
                            typeAdapter = bTypeAdapter;
                        } else if ( jsonObject.has("fieldC") ) {
                            typeAdapter = cTypeAdapter;
                        } else {
                            throw new JsonParseException("Unsupported JSON element: " + jsonElement);
                        }
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        final T value = (T) typeAdapter.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
                        return value;
                    }
                }
                        .nullSafe();
            }
        })
        .create();
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. But it seems that your solution makes the implementation more verbose and harder to maintain than a set of `if..else` expressions. But looking at my question I might be asking for something impossible or hard to achieve.

Comment: @PauloOliveira Yeah, Gson is just a base, and the most you can do about that is either implement a generic solution (and possibly share it to others) or use a ad-hoc solution (possibly using a codegen). If you want it "less verbose", you can sacrifice some performance and register the rules from the first example, still having it centralized and done at the deserialization level (hiding all the verbosity under the hood). Manual if/else-s are harder to maintain unless you have a codegen.